# using pandas Series.rolling with DateOffset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, analysis

Python, Pandas, data analysis here.

so what I am trying to do is identify the busiest 60-minute time interval from a large set of apache server logs. I have extracted the timestamps from the log is into a list.

time_recieved is a list that has values like this

```
[
1995-07-01T00:01:18-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:11:45-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:11:45-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:11:45-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:46-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:47-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:50-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:11-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:18-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:22-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:22-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:23-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:26-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:27-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:31-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00,
1995-07-01T00:14:36-04:00,
]
```

my goal is that along this list of timestamps, I will be able to get the count of the 60 minute interval beginning at any one of those points. Once I get the rolling window going, I think I can handle that.

on the pandas documentation:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html
i found the following entry about the window argument 
"
window : int, or offset
Size of the moving window. This is the number of observations used for calculating the statistic. Each window will be a fixed size.
If its an offset then this will be the time period of each window. Each window will be a variable sized based on the observations included in the time-period. This is only valid for datetimelike indexes. This is new in 0.19.0
"

I am using pandas 19.2 the option of using the window being variable sized based on the observations in the time period sounds like exactly what I want. So I tried to implement it:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
def busiest_timeframe(data,timeframe = 60):    
    time_window = DateOffset(minutes = 60)
    print (type(time_window))
    series = pd.Series(data)
    series.rolling(time_window).count()
    return series  

busiest_tf = busiest_timeframe(time_received)
```

i get the following error: 
    raise ValueError("window must be an integer")

```
ValueError: window must be an integer
```

is there some other offset object I am using? does this pandas feature not work? did I misunderstand the documentation?

Thank you in advance for your help and advice!

Comment: `series.rolling` goes over a _number_ of observations, not over a _time window_. So, the first parameter must be an integer number.

Comment: You may be looking for a resampler, not a window: `series.resample('60M').count()`. However, the resampler is not rolling, it simply splits your series into 60-minute groups.

Comment: DYZ  the pandas documentation says "If its an offset then this will be the time period of each window. Each window will be a variable size based on the observations included in the time_period'

Comment: "_This is new in 0.19.0_". Is your pandas at least 0.19.0?

Comment: I am using pandas 19.2, I checked the pd.__version__

Comment: I thought that maybe the word "offset" used in the documentation means a different kind of offset? but I'm not sure which. I found index dateoffset in pandas documentation but it looks out of date or unused.

Answer (score 1):

Try offset aliases instead of DateOffset:

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases

Example from [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]},
                  index = [pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                           pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')])

print(df.rolling('2s').count())
```

Output:

```
                       B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03  2.0
2013-01-01 09:00:05  NaN
2013-01-01 09:00:06  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I dont know how to use series.rolling, it seems as as if you didnt set it as an index and thats why it didnt work. But even then I got errors, so here is an alternative (maybe really ugly way), so if someone else has a better way it would be best if you listen to others.

So yeah it uses boolean indexing. Play around with the Code (lots of print statements) and maybe change the >= and <= to > and < if you want.

```
liste=[
"1995-07-01T00:01:18-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:01:19-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:11:45-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:11:45-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:11:45-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:43-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:46-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:47-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:48-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:50-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:13:53-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:11-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:17-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:18-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:20-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:21-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:22-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:22-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:23-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:24-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:26-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:27-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:30-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:31-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:32-04:00",
"1995-07-01T00:14:36-04:00"
]
import pandas as pd

from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
def busiest_timeframe(data,timeframe = 1):

    series = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(data), format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') #maybe you dont need the to_datetime here. I did.
    df=series.to_frame(name="time")
    df["count"]=[df[(df["time"] >= x) & (df["time"] <= (x+pd.Timedelta(seconds=timeframe)))].size for x in df["time"].values] #change seconds to minutes or whatever you want
    highest_index=df["count"].idxmax()
    #print(df.ix[highest_index]["time"])
    df2=df[(df["time"] >= df.ix[highest_index]["time"]) & (df["time"] <= (df.ix[highest_index]["time"]+pd.Timedelta(seconds=timeframe)))] #change seconds here to th same as above
    return df2
print(busiest_timeframe(liste))
```